# Struts2 passing JavaBean to action as parameter

Tags: parameters, struts2, javabeans

How can I pass JavaBean object to action as parameter?

for example I have action(dataBean is a JavaBean):

1)

```
public class SimpleAction extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private DataBean dataBean;


public String execute() throws Exception {


    System.out.println("SimpleAction executing");
    System.out.println(dataBean.getMinDate().toString());

    return SUCCESS;
}


public DataBean getDataBean() {
    return dataBean;
}


public void setDataBean(DataBean dataBean) {
    this.dataBean = dataBean;
}
```

2)then I want to call this action from jsp with not string parameter(dataBean):

for example:

```
<s:url  var="simple" action="simple">
  <s:param name = "dataBean" value="#request.dataBean"/>
</s:url>
```

3) Am I need to make some conversion of type from dataBean object to string or vice versa?

4) Is it possible to use such construction in Struts2?

5) Please explain and also example of code would be good

Comment: Everything what is being submitted is string. You need a converter. See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html.

Comment: Why do you need that ?

Comment: You could serialize a bean somehow when passing as a request parameter, it isn't necessary if you submit the form.